# JavaScript Regex: How to match terms outside of the quotation marks?

Tags: javascript, regex

The goal is to match `/ and /gu` and `/ or /gu` and replace them with `' AND '` and `' OR '` but if they are inside of the quotation marks, the replacement should not have taken place.

For example, if the string is `term:"cat and dog" and keyword:view or keyword:impression` it should be replaced into `term:"cat and dog" AND keyword:view OR keyword:impression`.

---

It turns out it is possible to use one REGEX only for this problem.

```js
regex = /\b(and|or)\b(?=(?:[^"]*"[^"]*")*[^"]*$)/g;

regex.test("cat and dog") // true
regex.test("cat or dog") // true
regex.test("\"cat and dog\"") // false
regex.test("\"cat and dog\" or \"cat or dog\"") // true
regex.test("\"cat and dog\" plus \"cat or dog\"") // false
```

So, basically we can do this:

```js
"\"cat and dog\" and \"cat or dog\"".replace(/\b(and|or)\b(?=(?:[^"]*"[^"]*")*[^"]*$)/g, x => x.toUpperCase())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can try a regex replacement here, with the help of an alternation:

```js
var input = "term:\"cat and dog\" and keyword:view or keyword:impression";
var output = input.replace(/".*?"|\w+/g, (x) => x.match(/^(?:and|or)$/i) ? x.toUpperCase() : x);
console.log(output);
```

The trick here is to first search for `"..."` terms.  That failing, we match any other word, one at a time.  Then, in the callback replacement, we ignore doubly quoted terms, thereby ignoring `and` or `or` inside double quotes.  We only make an actual replacement for `and`/`or` by uppercasing them.